# What determines the display name of my app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I just submitted an app to the App Store through Xcode. I set up the name in iTunes Connect, but I just realized that I was still using the working title in Xcode. Does this mean that when users download my app, the working title be shown beneath the app icon, or will the iTunes Connect title be used?

Comment: After downloading the bundle display name (from xcode) will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "appName" on itunes connect will define the name displayed on the app store.

The name that will be under your app icon is the `Product Name` defined in xcode.
You can find it on `Targets > YourProject > Build Settings > Packaging`.

**EDIT :** changing the `Bundle Display Name` in your info.plist should do the work.

Comment: Is that neccessary? I just realized that this changes my Bundle Identifier, which messes with my Game Center setup. Isn't changing just the Bundle Display Name enough?

Comment: I think you are right ! I think it is better to change the `Product Name` when you want to rename your app (totally), but changing the Bundle Display Name is enough.

Comment: Ok thanks. I changed the Bundle name too, just in case. Hopefully everything will be named correctly now :)

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle Display Name in the app's plist is what is displayed under the icon.  This display name can be changed independent of the project name, product name, or the Bundle ID suffix.  The name displayed by the App Store is set in iTunes Connect, and can also be set independent from any of the other 4 or 5 "names" for an app.